# Panels creates very long css class names

Tags: css, drupal, class, panels

I'm using Panels, which creates very long CSS class names. How can I shorten the css code?
My HTML code in my frontage is 450K. How can I optimize it?

thank you

Comment: [GZIP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip)

Comment: 450k is ... impressive ... even assuming gzip/deflate to ~50% size (pulled out of my [adjective] [noun]), that's like a quarter of a megabyte. Wow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Views and CCK, the Panels module adds a lot of divs and classes for you, in an attempt to make it easier to theme. The [Semantic Views](http://drupal.org/project/semanticviews) and [Semantic CCK](http://drupal.org/project/semantic_cck) modules allow you to customize and simplify the output. It wouldn't be trivial, but you could write something similar for Panels.

Otherwise, practically everything in Panels (and in Drupal in general) gets output through a theme function, so you could [override those theme functions](http://drupal.org/node/11811) to strip out some of the unnecessary divs and classes. Of course, that's what the modules above do, though they do it programmatically rather than by manually overriding individual functions.